# Comparing Minimum and Maximum - Negative Infinity to specified max value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a variable that I need to check if its above a maximum range but has no minimum range.

```
var rangeChecks = [
    {
      name: "speed", number: 1, min: 20, max: 50
    },
    {
      name: "voltage", number: 2, min: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, max: 40
    },
    {
      name: "temperature", number: 4, min: 100, max: 200
    }];

  for(var z=0; z<rangeChecks.length; z++){

    var rangeCheck = rangeChecks[z];
   var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(rangeCheck.name);
    template[rangeCheck.name] = values[rangeCheck.number];

    if((values[rangeCheck.number] <= rangeCheck.min)|| (values[rangeCheck.number] >= rangeCheck.max)){

    /*MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent()});*/
      Logger.log("Name: "+rangeCheck.name+" Number: "+rangeCheck.number+ " Value: "+values[rangeCheck.number]);

    } 

  }
```

I have this. But `voltage` does not have a minimum value, I tried using `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, but it isn't working. Is there something similar to that?

Thanks.

edit: I have to to set a variable first and have it equals to `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and it worked instead of directly assigning to min. No idea why. But it worked.

Comment: Explain *but it isn't working*

Comment: I tried to google the equivalent of ``Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY``, I couldn't find it. This may be a Javascript command which is not applicable to Google Script. I was wondering what is the equivalent? In my code, I need the ``IF`` statements to be in that way because I have max and min but some of my parameters may only need a MAX or a MIN. I have tried to run the if statement without ``voltage`` ``min`` value, the if loop doesn't trigger.

Comment: D3F, It supports. Problem is elsewhere. Easy way to test it is `var y = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;Logger.log(y<-1).log(y>1)` You can also just use `-Infinity`(notice the color change in the editor- showing it recognizes)

Comment: You're checking for the same condition twice in your `if` statement; you have`(values[rangeCheck.number] <= rangeCheck.min)|| (values[rangeCheck.number] <= rangeCheck.min)`. Both of these will return `false` because you're checking if they're smaller than infinity, and you also never change `min`, so this will happen every time.

Comment: Apologies for that @AMolina. I did changed already, this was a copy paste I didn't notice I copied wrongly.

Comment: I am not sure why. I have to set ``Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;`` to a variable FIRST before being able to use it. If I set it directly onto my min / max(POSITIVE_INFINITY). It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to to set a variable first and have it equals to `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and it worked instead of directly assigning to min. No idea why. But it worked.

```
var negativemin = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

var rangeChecks = [
    {
      name: "speed", number: 1, min: 20, max: 50
    },
    {
      name: "voltage", number: 2, min: negativemin, max: 40
    },
    {
      name: "temperature", number: 4, min: 100, max: 200
    }];
```